# Getting Python to accept a csv into postgreSQL table with ":" in the headers

Tags: postgresql, csv, insert, sql-insert, pyodbc

I receive a .csv export every 10 minutes that I'd like to import into a postgreSQL server. Working with a test csv, I got everything to work, but didn't take notice that my actual csv file has a forced ":" at the end of each column header (but not on the first header for some reason)(built into the back-end of the exporter, so I cant get it removed, already asked the company). So I added the ":"s to my test csv as shown in the link,

[image: header example]

My insert into functions no longer work and give me syntax errors. First I'm trying to add them using the following code,

```
print("Reading file contents and copying into table...")
with open('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test2.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    columns = next(readCSV) #skips the header row
    query = 'insert into test({0}) values ({1})'
    query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
    for data in readCSV:
        cursor.execute(query, data)
    con.commit()
```

Resulting in '42601' error near ":" in the second column header.

The results are the same while actually listing column headers and ? ? ?s out in the INSERT INTO section.

What is the syntax to get the script to accept ":" on column headers? If there's no way, is there a way to scan through headers and remove the ":" at the end of each?

Comment: Do: `columns_fixed = [col.split(':')[0] for col in columns]` which yields `['id', 'year', 'month', 'day']` and then use that in the `query_format`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `:` is a special character, if your column is named `year:` in the DB, you must double quote its name --> `select "year:" from test;`

You are getting a PG error because you are referencing the unquoted column name (`insert into test({0})`), so add double quotes there.

`query = 'insert into test("year:","day:", "etc:") values (...)'`

That being said, it might be simpler to remove every occurrence of `:` in your csv's 1st line

Answer (score 0):

Much appreciated JGH and Adrian. I went with your suggestion to remove every occurrence of : by adding the following line after the first `columns = ...` statement

```
columns = [column.strip(':') for column in columns]
```

It worked well.